# Converting Currency into USD using AMP script is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, ssjs, cloudpage

I tried to convert currency into USD, but instead of converting into USD it's moving to decimal place.

My code is

%%[

Var @num

Set @num = formatcurrency("123.45678", "en-Us")

] %%

My output: $123.46

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

formatCurrency formats the currency, i.e. it makes it "look the way a currency would be written in en-US format".

It is not connected to exchange rates >>  You can expect no conversion. You'd have to look towards Sales Cloud and work off a field based on "multi-currency" logic. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_currency.htm&type=5